# API resource location a7c78d38-31a8-417e-ba6b-7e58b352f304 is not registered on

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I'm trying nuget caching in Azure Pipelines. On running the pipeline, I'm facing this error.

```
Resolving key:
 - nuget                 [string]
 - "Windows_NT"          [string]
 - **/packages.lock.json [file pattern; matches: 1]
   - s\NugetPackage\NugetPackage\packages.lock.json --> C50B5A946B314B4828AFA48FEA20E6387F9159D2B6F286C5FFD55C6873971D2E
Resolved to: nuget|"Windows_NT"|5fUBmn2K3dE1mNtjhbzAPEcBDcZt1N92ZcpVdzKRIxs=
Getting a pipeline cache artifact with the following fingerprint: `nuget|"Windows_NT"|5fUBmn2K3dE1mNtjhbzAPEcBDcZt1N92ZcpVdzKRIxs=`.
##[error]API resource location a7c78d38-31a8-417e-ba6b-7e58b352f304 is not registered on https://[url]/[project]/.
Finishing: NuGet Cache
```

Other Info:
Using Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1

The pipeline:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  NUGET_PACKAGES: ''

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'NuGet tool installer'

- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'NuGet Cache'
  inputs:
    key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json'
    path: '$(NUGET_PACKAGES)'
    cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'
```

I'm trying this on a .net framework project having installed Newtonsoft.json from Nuget.

Cache@V2 ansible task is the one failing with message "API resource location a7c78d38-31a8-417e-ba6b-7e58b352f304 is not registered on"

The query is whether this Cache@v2 task is supported on Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1 on-premise?

If yes, then what is the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cache@2` task is not supported on-premises. It works on Azure DevOps, but it doesn't work on Azure DevOps On-Premise Server ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13937)).